# How can I use PixelGrabber (JAVA) in order to count total pixels and compare different pixels between two images

Tags: java

so i have been working on this program that initially should be able to compare whether two images are different or are identical, currently i got that part working, but i want to be able to see the percentage of difference between the two pictures, so i was hoping i could get some tips or some solution that might help me make it better, Initially i was considering counting the total similar pixels and then counting the total pixels and just getting the percentage between the two however i'm not sure what would be the best solution in this situation, here's the code that i have right now..

> package scantestapp; import java.awt.Image; import java.awt.Toolkit;
>   import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber; import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
>
> public class CompareImage  {
>
> ```
> public static String field;
> public static boolean fi;
>
> static void processImage(String file1, String file2)
> {
>
>     Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
>     Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file2);
>
>     try 
>     {    
>         PixelGrabber grab1 = new PixelGrabber(image1, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
>         PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(image2, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
>
>         int[] data1 = null;
>
>         if (grab1.grabPixels()) 
>         {
>             int width = grab1.getWidth();
>             int height = grab1.getHeight();
>             data1 = new int[width * height];
>             data1 = (int[]) grab1.getPixels();
>         }
>
>         int[] data2 = null;
>
>         if (grab2.grabPixels()) {
>             int width = grab2.getWidth();
>             int height = grab2.getHeight();
>             data2 = new int[width * height];
>             data2 = (int[]) grab2.getPixels();
>         }
>
>         System.out.println("Are these Images Identical ?: " + java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2));
>           MainMenu MM = new MainMenu();
>           fi = java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2);
>           field = "Are These Images Identical ?: " + fi;
>           DisplayResult(data1, data2);
>
>     } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
>         e1.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>
> public void caller(String file1, String file2){
>
>     MainMenu MM = new MainMenu();
>
>     processImage(file1, file2);   
> }
>
> public static void DisplayResult(int Data1[], int Data2[]){
>
>     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Are these Images Identical ?: " + java.util.Arrays.equals(Data1, Data2), "NOTICE!",
> ```
>
> JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
>
> ```
> }
>
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>
> } }
> ```

Looking forward to your answers, thank you!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: As far as I see you are converting the image into an array of pixels storing them in 2 `int[]` and comparing them. This should work, if you are looking for something more specific you have to *specify*

Comment: I would like a way in order to get the percentage of changes between the two images, like for example when you input two images and for example it says image 1 is 60 % similar to image 2

Comment: How do you calculate if an image is 60% = other image?

Comment: I'm not looking if it's exactly 60%, I want to be able to get the percentage of difference between the two

Comment: for example, image 1 is x% of image 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd confess this is a very naive attempt. This approach fails on:

- 2 images which have different resolutions but essentially look same to the eye
- 2 images which have slightly different color gradient but are visually similar

Additionally there are modern deep learning approaches which you should also check.

Now having that out of the way, you can do something like this:

```
public class CompareImage {

    static void processImage(String file1, String file2) {

        Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
        Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file2);

        try {
            PixelGrabber grab1 = new PixelGrabber(image1, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
            PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(image2, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);

            int[] data1 = null;

            if (grab1.grabPixels()) {
                int width = grab1.getWidth();
                int height = grab1.getHeight();
                data1 = new int[width * height];
                data1 = (int[]) grab1.getPixels();
            }

            int[] data2 = null;

            if (grab2.grabPixels()) {
                int width = grab2.getWidth();
                int height = grab2.getHeight();
                data2 = new int[width * height];
                data2 = (int[]) grab2.getPixels();
            }

            System.out.println("Are these Images Identical ?: " + java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2));
            float similarity = compare(data1, data2);
            System.out.println("The similarity percent between the 2 images is: " + similarity + "%");

        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static float compare(int[] data1, int[] data2) {
        if (data1.length == data2.length) {
            float totalPixelCount = data1.length;
            float matchedPixelCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
                if (data1[i] == data2[i])
                    matchedPixelCount++;
            }
            return matchedPixelCount / totalPixelCount * 100;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        processImage("C:\\Users\\absin\\Downloads\\img_28136253.png",
                "C:\\\\Users\\\\absin\\\\Downloads\\\\img_281362531.png");
    }
}
```

gives an output:

`Are these Images Identical ?: false
The similarity percent between the 2 images is: 97.46519%`

on images : 
[image: Unbotched Image]

AND

[image: Botched Image]

Notice the slight botching with blue ink which contributes to ~3% pixels failing comparison.

Comment: I was actually hoping to get something like this, I have never done this before so i have no knowledge about image processing, either way, thank you so much for showing me how to do it, I'm most likely going to research this some more before I finalised the process, I most likely am gonna work on something that simply resizes the images to a similar size(resolution), as for the colour, it doesn't matter in my case because i'm scanning black and white documents with this mainly, again, thanks a lot !